# Redux toolkit createAsyncThunk using Parameter

Tags: redux-toolkit

I need your help.

We implemented createAsyncThunk using the Redux Toolkit.

However, as shown in the picture, I need a function to change ChannelId flexibly. Can't I use the parameter in createAsyncThunk?

How can I use it if I can?
Or is there any other way?

I am sorry that the quality of the question is low because I am Korean using a translator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT6WF.png)

[image]

```js
// ACTION
export const getYoutubeList_PlayList = createAsyncThunk(
    "GET/YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST",
    async (data, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get<youtubeResponse>(
                `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=${youTubeAcsses.apiKey}&channelId=${channelId}&part=snippet&maxResults=30`
            )
            return data
        } catch (err: any) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({
                errorMessage: '호출에 실패했습니다.'
            })
        }
    }
);

// SLICE
const youtube_PlaylistSlice = createSlice({
    name: "YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    // createAsyncThunk 호출 처리 = extraReducers
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(getYoutubeList_PlayList.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.loading = true;
            })
            .addCase(getYoutubeList_PlayList.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<youtubeResponse>) => {
                state.loading = false;
                state.data = action.payload;
            })
            .addCase(getYoutubeList_PlayList.rejected, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
                state.error = action.payload;
            });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named both the incoming argument `data` as well as the result of your axios call. That will "shadow" the original `data` and you cannot access it any more. Give those two variables different names.

Here I called it `arg`, which allows you to access `arg.channelId`.

```js
export const getYoutubeList_PlayList = createAsyncThunk(
    "GET/YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST",
    async (arg, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get<youtubeResponse>(
                `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=${youTubeAcsses.apiKey}&channelId=${arg.channelId}&part=snippet&maxResults=30`
            )
            return data
        } catch (err: any) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({
                errorMessage: '호출에 실패했습니다.'
            })
        }
    }
);
```

You would now dispatch this as `dispatch(getYoutubeList_PlayList({ channelId: 5 }))`

Comment: hi !! thx your answer but this problem .. how fix it?

dispatch(getYoutubeList_PlayList({ channelId: 5 }))

Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.  TS2554

Comment: Give your `arg` a typescript type: `async (arg: { channelId: number }, thunkAPI) => {`